# 403 error in CloudFront AWS for my amazon educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I am using an aws educate account provided by my college instructor to learn about serverless application development in aws. I am trying to use CloudFront for Content Delivery Network services but I get the following error. How can this be resolved.

> **com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::127746452845:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user616202=riwaj.chalise@deerwalk.edu.np is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:ListDistributions with an explicit deny (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 50ae6438-3196-452a-bcf9-80aaa5cf5e7c; Proxy: null)**

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? Can my educator provide me the access to this service(cloudfront)?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your user doesn't have privilege to access AWS cloudfront. You can ask your educator for the same.

There is something called **AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)** which helps to create users and manage access for each users or group of users to AWS services and resources securely.

Comment: So my instructor is the one who can change my IAM to provide access to cloud front?

Comment: Yes, if your instructor has access to IAM and he is one managing this aws account